# Closing embedded object after editing

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, exit, mailmerge

I'm having some trouble performing a mail merge using an embedded Word file. Essentially

I'm trying to build a macro to:

- Open an embedded Word file (let's say the file is Object(2))
- Connect the Export sheet to the word fie
- Preview the results
- Update the table of contents
- Export the file as a PDF
- Close the word application leaving the completed PDF open

Here's the code that I'm upto so far, but it won't close the WINWORD application afterwards:

```
Public Sub fExportSVF()

    Dim WdObj As Object
    Dim WdApp As Word.Application
    Dim WdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    Dim strPeril As String
    Dim strClaimNumber As String
    Dim strPHName As String
    Dim strSaveLoc As String
    Dim strWbName As String
    Dim strTempLoc As String
    Dim xlObj As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Call fUnhideSheet("EXPORT_DATA")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    strTempLoc = Environ("TEMP") & Int((9999 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1) & ".xlsm"

    strWbName = Worksheets("Settings").Range("B4").Value
    strPeril = Worksheets("Settings").Range("B3").Value
    strClaimNumber = Worksheets("Settings").Range("B1").Value
    strPHName = Worksheets("Settings").Range("B2").Value

    If Dir(strTempLoc) <> "" Then Kill strTempLoc

    Set xlObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    xlObj.CopyFile ThisWorkbook.FullName, strTempLoc, True

    strSaveLoc = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & strClaimNumber & _
    " - " & strPHName & " - " & strPeril & ".pdf"

    Select Case strPeril
        Case "Acc"
            intIndex = 2
        Case "Acci"
            intIndex = 3
        Case "AD"
            intIndex = 4
        Case "Es"
            intIndex = 5
        Case "Fi"
            intIndex = 6
        Case "Fld"
            intIndex = 7
        Case "Impt"
            intIndex = 8
        Case "St"
            intIndex = 9
        Case "Th"
            intIndex = 10
    End Select

    Set WdObj = Worksheets("Settings").OLEObjects(intIndex)

    WdObj.Activate
    WdObj.Object.Application.Visible = False

    Set WdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set WdDoc = WdApp.ActiveDocument

    WdApp.Visible = True

    WdDoc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

    WdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
        strWbName _
        , ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", _
        WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
        Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Connection:= _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & strTempLoc & _
        ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet " & _
        "OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine " _
        , SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `EXPORT_DATA$`", SQLStatement1:="", _
        SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
    WdDoc.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = wdToggle

    WdDoc.TablesOfContents(1).Update

    WdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat outputfilename:=strSaveLoc, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

    WdApp.ActiveDocument.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges

    Set WdApp = Nothing
    Set WdObj = Nothing

    Kill strTempLoc

    Call fHideSheet("EXPORT_DATA")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

So it does everything apart from close the WINWORD application. Apart from that, I've noticed that if there's another document already open, it will make that invisible as well.

Any help please?

Cheers

**EDIT:**
Also, the machines that this code will be running on will have both Word 97 and Word 2007 on them. The document will need to open and edited in Word 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line (which sets WdApp to an existing instance of Word, if any):

`Set WdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")`

to this, which creates a new instance of Word, to prevent closing other documents which might be open:

`Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")`

To close `wdApp` use the Quit method:

`wdApp.Quit`